# Ajax request from PHP replaces div

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to get the text from an input field, get it with Ajax, send it to PHP and then show it on the page inside a div.

The problem is that the div, once with the text, the second time, it replaces it.

[Javascript&Ajax](http://hastebin.com/hojufovehi.xml)

PHP:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET['input'];
echo "<div class='input'><strong>You:</strong><p> $input </p></div>"
?>
```

Edit: Clarifying...

I have one text field (we'll call it 1) and a div (we'll call it two).

I take the text typed in the **1** and send it through AJAX to PHP file.
Now I take that text from PHP with Ajax again, and display it on the **2**.
When I do this again, the text that is already processed in **2** gets erased and replaced by the newer text. And I don't want them. I want the new text showing below the old text, and so on...

Comment: That's because you clear it out here `document.getElementById("sendtext").value = "";` Your question is very heard to understand, can you clarify ?

Comment: @kennypu You can see it in the Javascript&Ajax link.

http://hastebin.com/hojufovehi.xml

Comment: so do `$('#whatever').html($('#whatever').html() + ajaxresponse)`.

Comment: I really don't understand, @Marc B .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code replaces the entire contents of your `'text'` div with the result of the ajax call:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Instead, append the result to preserve the previous contents:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

**Edit**:
Quick example based on your original code http://jsfiddle.net/vRSB3/

Comment: Hah, just a simple "+". Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user1877016 you also might look into using a javascript library like http://jquery.com/ it can make common operations like ajax requests and DOM manipulation much much easier.